# Why I cannot run multiple Print() statements in command prompt?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run this following code

[image]

It runs ok directly from the third.py file

[image]

But if I type the code in the Command Prompt it gives me en error

[image]

Can anyone point out my mistake here.

Comment: Don't post code as images

Comment: First you need to understand how terminal works. After while you should end your statement. ‘n=5’ is statement 1, ‘while’ is another statement, ‘print(“blastoff!”)’ is your third. Try as it is.

Comment: To clarify, if you used an editor like IDLE then you would enter lines 1 through 4 exactly as you did, but before entering line 5 (the blastoff line) you first need to hit return again to end the while statement.  The while will execute, and you will see the printout of the countdown from 5 to 1. THEN you will enter line 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the code would look like if you opened a file using IDLE.  Note the indentation is necessary.  The blastoff line begins in column 1 because it is the first statement after the while loop.

```
n = 5
while n > 0 :
    print(n)
    n = n - 1
print('Blastoff!')
```

In the IDLE interactive mode, you would enter lines 1 and 2.  You would see that after entering line 2 that the prompt automatically indented so that you can begin entering statements that are part of the while loop, and the >>> prompt disappears, so that you would enter lines 3 and 4 like this:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> while n > 0 :
        print(n)
        n = n - 1
```

At this point, you need to press enter to complete the while loop.

If you enter the blastoff line before doing so at the same indentation as lines 3 and 4 then you will create a logic error where the code will work but it will be incorrect.

If you backspace and enter the blast off line then you will get the syntax error you encountered.

So press enter to complete while loop.  It will execute and produce output like so:

```
5
4
3
2
1
>>>
```

...and then it will return your prompt back again.  You can then enter the blastoff line after the prompt:

```
>>> print('Blastoff!')
```

...and the output will be:

```
Blastoff!
```